# Change a TextBlock's Style using a DataTrigger, combined with MultiBinding

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a `Label` to which I bind a `DateTime` and a `string` using `MultiBinding`.
For the `DateTime` I want to check for `.MinValue` using a `DataTrigger`.

This is my current code where I change the `Text` of the `TextBlock`:

```
    <TextBlock >
    <TextBlock.Text>
          <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}  {1:dd.MM.yyyy} {2:HH:mm:ss}">
            <Binding Path="myString" />
            <Binding Path="myDate" />
            <Binding Path="myDate" />
            </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
   </TextBlock>
```

And this is how I want to change the Date to "-" if it equals `DateTime.MinValue`:

```
<TextBlock.Style>
  <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=MyDate, StringFormat=d}" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyDate}" Value="{x:Static sys:DateTime.MinValue}">
          <Setter Property="Text" Value="-" />
       </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

Unfortunately I am not too familiar with XAML. I would love to see those two combined. So if myDate equals DateTime.MinDate the `TextBox`'s `Text`would read `-` and if there was an actual `DateTime` in `myDate` then use the `StringFormat` that I provided. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use a `MultiValueConverter` to produce the final desired output and skip the `Trigger` that way.

Comment: You mean, put the logic into code?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You create a class that derives from `IMultiValueConverter` and in its `Convert` method you will have an array of objects in order of your `Binding` which you can then try-cast to the underlying type and convert to what you need. E.g. if it is `MinValue` return "-" instead of the `ToString()` formatted date/time.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use a `MultivalueConverter` for your `TextBlock`.

This is a rough example:

```
public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string retVal = "-";

        foreach(var currentValue in values)
        {
            if(currentValue is string)
            {
                retVal = dosomething;
                //break here if you satisfied;
            }
            else if(currentValue is DateTime)
            {
                DateTime theVal = (DateTime)currentValue;
                if(theVal == DateTime.MinValue)
                {
                    retVal = "-";
                }
                else
                {
                    retVal = theVal.ToString("Format here...");
                }
                //break if satisfied
            }

        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new object[] { Binding.DoNothing, Binding.DoNothing };
    }
}
```

Here is the corresponding XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <yourNamespace:MyConverter x:Key="MultiValueConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
        <Binding Path="myString" />
        <Binding Path="myDate" />
        <Binding Path="myDate" />
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

Put the desired logic into the convert method. The order of the values in the `values` array is in the order of your bindings. This way you can stitch the desired result together based on the inputs.